# Import Json file into Mongoose

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to import a JSON file to a data base Mongoose. This should be a script that should be run daily.

I have my JSON as follows :

```
[
 {
   "grant_title": "name SRL",
   "id": "30579843531",
   "total_amount": "551954"
},{
   "grant_title": "AADI CAPIF ASOCIACION CIVIL",
   "id": "30574449967",
   "total_amount": "37050"
},{
   "grant_title": "LA CAMPAÑOLA S.A",
   "id": "23311183419",
   "total_amount": "139292"
  }
]
```

I need this information to be stored in a database .

This should be whether or if a script NodeJS (express). Please be clear , because I am a beginner .

Comment: WHY ARE YOU SHOUTING?

Comment: Sorry, my english is poor :( . I need help. :)

Answer (score 6):

Let's take this gradually.  First off you are going to need to either create a CRON job, or use a NodeJS scheduler such as [agenda](https://github.com/rschmukler/agenda) to execute your function at a time interval.

Now... inside your function you need to load your JSON file into NodeJS.

```
var json = require('/path/to/file.json');
```

Finally... use insertMany to do a bulk insert into your collection.

```
db.collectionName.insertMany(json, function(err,result) {
   if (err) {
     // handle error
   } else {
     // handle success
   }
});
```

EDIT: Here is an example of using Agenda in NodeJS to run a program daily at 11:30 AM

```
var Agenda = require('agenda');

startScheduler = function() {
    // Set the scheduler utilizing Agenda
    var agenda = new Agenda({db: {address: 'url/to/database'}});

    agenda.define('RUN AT 1130 AM', function(job, done) {
        // your function goes here...
        done();
    });

    agenda.on('ready', function() {
        // CRON SYNTAX
        // * * * * * *
        // Minute / Hour / Day / Month / Day of week (0-6) Sunday-Saturday
        agenda.every('30 11 * * *', 'RUN AT 1130 AM'); // Run daily at 11:30 AM

        agenda.start();
    });
};

startScheduler();
```

Comment: After struggling a little bit with `db.collectionName.insertMany(...)` (error _'Cannot read property 'insertMany' of undefined'_), I've ended up writing something equivalent to `const mongoose = require('mongoose'); /* ... DB connexion ... */ mongoose.connection.db.collection('collectionName').insertMany(...)`. However my suggestion is a completely schema-less approach (possibly Ok for ex. if you aim to import data from a reliable export without bothering with schemas declarations) ; in most situations using Mongoose Schemas would be safer.

Comment: ... furthermore if you use Mongoose Schemas, if you insert a date string in your JSON data, it will still have the type "Date" in Mongo (instead of being stored as a raw string). Same goes certainly for other data types.